# Oracle - get table name from sql text

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a column in a table with simple sql queries and I want to regexp_substr the table name from them.
Examples of texts:

```
SELECT PT.PT_PARTY_NAME VALUE,PT.PT_PARTY_NAME LABEL
    FROM DWH_OWNER.DWH_ACCOUNTS ACC,
         DWH_OWNER.DWH_PARTIES PT
   WHERE ACC.ACC_SOURCE_ID = :P_DOMVAL_REF1
    AND ACC.ACC_PT_KEY = PT.PT_KEY
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT QRMPT_PRODUCT VALUE, QRMPT_PRODUCT LABEL FROM   
DWH_OWNER.DWH_QRM_PRODUCT_TYPES ORDER BY VALUE
```

So, I need to find the "FROM", skip some whitespaces then get the first word.
I'm not interested for the moment in the second table.

What I've done:

```
select 
    sql, 
    regexp_substr(upper(sql), '(\s)FROM(\s)*([[:alnum:]]|\.|_)*') tablename
from my_table_with_queries;
```

Output:

```
 FROM DWH_OWNER.DWH_ACCOUNTS
FROM   
    DWH_OWNER.DWH_QRM_PRODUCT_TYPES
```

What's wrong with my qyery:
  It outputs the tablename with the "FROM " before the table name. I want the table name directly, without whitespaces.

Desired output:

```
DWH_OWNER.DWH_ACCOUNTS
DWH_OWNER.DWH_QRM_PRODUCT_TYPES
```

**EDIT:** 
I managed to do `regexp_substr(tablename, '(\w|_|\.)+', 1,2)` over the previous step to do the tablename clean. But It is possible to get the desired output with a single regexp?

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d) should be an sqlfiddle, but the site does not work in this moment. The query:

```
  with a as (
select 'SELECT PT.PT_PARTY_NAME VALUE,PT.PT_PARTY_NAME LABEL
    FROM DWH_OWNER.DWH_ACCOUNTS ACC,
         DWH_OWNER.DWH_PARTIES PT
   WHERE ACC.ACC_SOURCE_ID = :P_DOMVAL_REF1
    AND ACC.ACC_PT_KEY = PT.PT_KEY' sql from dual
 union all

 select 'SELECT DISTINCT QRMPT_PRODUCT VALUE, QRMPT_PRODUCT LABEL FROM   
DWH_OWNER.DWH_QRM_PRODUCT_TYPES ORDER BY VALUE' from dual
  )

select 
       regexp_substr(upper(sql), '\sFROM\s*(\w|\.|_)*') tablename, sql
from a;
```

Comment: Could it be simplified to `\sFROM\s*([\w.]*)`?

Comment: @Thomas with minor modification - `regexp_substr(sql,'\sFROM\s*(\w|\.)*')` -  yes, but will still output the FROM. That's my problem.

Comment: Why are you using capturing groups around `\s` ?

Comment: I don't know what is a _capturing group_. I'm beginner with regexps. Not with Oracle, but with regexps yes :)

Comment: With your expression I get only ' FROM '.

Comment: Will you want the second table at some point? And will you need to allow for CTEs and inline views, and subqueries? What is the end goal - to find all tables the statement refers to?

Comment: @Alex i will need the other tables, but the queries are flat. No subqueries. The tables are first step, columns the second, but that's my job. I want only to know how to get next word after specific word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than try to write your own parser, you could let Oracle parse it for you via `explain plan`, and then look at the plan table to see which objects it refers to:

```
declare
  text varchar2(4000) := 'SELECT PT.PT_PARTY_NAME VALUE,PT.PT_PARTY_NAME LABEL
    FROM DWH_OWNER.DWH_ACCOUNTS ACC,
         DWH_OWNER.DWH_PARTIES PT
   WHERE ACC.ACC_SOURCE_ID = :P_DOMVAL_REF1
    AND ACC.ACC_PT_KEY = PT.PT_KEY';
begin
  execute immediate 'explain plan for ' || text;
end;
/

select distinct object_owner, object_name
from plan_table
where object_type = 'TABLE';

OBJECT_OWNER                   OBJECT_NAME                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DWH_OWNER                      DWH_ACCOUNTS                  
DWH_OWNER                      DWH_PARTIES
```

As @Aleksej suggested, if the optimiser only uses an index (so the execution plan shows index access/scan without hitting the table, because all the relevant columns are in the index) then the plan table only reports the index. You could allow for that by joining to the index view; if it hits the table too it'll just report it for both:

```
select distinct case when pt.object_type = 'INDEX' then ai.table_owner
    else pt.object_owner end as owner,
  case when pt.object_type = 'INDEX' then ai.table_name
    else pt.object_name end as table_name
from plan_table pt
left join all_indexes ai on ai.owner = pt.object_owner
and ai.index_name = pt.object_name
where pt.object_type in ('TABLE', 'INDEX');
```

You also need to make sure the plan table is empty before each explain plan call and query to avoid confusion, or set a statement ID so you can identify which tables related to the current query.

Comment: This is nice :) it's out of the box thinking.

Comment: Nice. Just one thing: what if the CBO would use an index instead of its table? could this be a problem or not?. I was trying to use DBMS_SQL, but it seems to me that it can give the columns, not the tables

Comment: @Aleksej - yes, I wondered about using dbms_sql.parse, but couldn't see a way to get the table info. Good point about the indexes. Hmm. Playing with Florin's query, if I have an index on `DHW_ACCOUNTS(ACC_SOURCE_ID, ACC_PT_KEY)` then plan display shows it doing a range scan on that index and doesn't say it hits the table; but my query still shows both tables.

Comment: @Aleksej - no, that's not true; I still had the previous query's plan in there. You could join to `all_indexes` to get the table name though, if the `object_type` is index.

Comment: In the end, a great, elegant solution. Thanks

Comment: It's a little bit embarrassing to  admit I posted an almost [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)